# Memory limits in systemd

Tags: systemd, celery

I am using systemd to run Celery, a python distributed task scheduler, on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server.

I have to schedule mostly long running tasks (taking several minutes to execute), which, depending on data, may end up eating a large amount of RAM. I want to put on some sort of safety measure in order to keep memory usage under control.

I have read [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html) that you can control how much RAM it's used by a systemd service using the `MemoryHigh` and `MemoryMax` options

I have used these options in my Celery service setup, and I watched what happens to a celery service when it reaches the given limits with `htop`.

The service stops the execution and is put on "D" state, but stays there and the allocated memory is not freed.

Is it possible for systemd to kill the memory eating process?

**UPDATE**

As suggested in the below comment I have tried some diagnostic, and I'm going to add other problem details.

The Linux server runs on a development virtual machine hosted by Virtual Box, running just the resource consuming task.

The `MemoryMax` setting is set as percentage (35%).

In the picture below you can see the process status in htop

[image: htop suspended process]

As suggested in the answer to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/940805/how-to-determine-the-cause-of-stuck-d-status-processes/942525#942525) question, the following is the content of the suspended process stack.

```
[<0>] __lock_page_or_retry+0x19b/0x2e0
[<0>] do_swap_page+0x5b4/0x960
[<0>] __handle_mm_fault+0x7a3/0x1290
[<0>] handle_mm_fault+0xb1/0x210
[<0>] __do_page_fault+0x281/0x4b0
[<0>] do_page_fault+0x2e/0xe0
[<0>] page_fault+0x45/0x50
[<0>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

Answer (score 5):

The process should already be killed if it reaches `MemoryMax=`. But if it passes `MemoryHigh=` then it may be suspended in the manner you describe. The problem is that if you reach `MemoryHigh=` then you may never reach `MemoryMax=`. If the process isn't actually releasing memory then it will just be mostly-suspended forever.

If you want the service to die if it uses a specific amount of memory, the don't specify `MemoryHigh=` at all, only `MemoryMax=`.

Ultimately your developers should find and resolve the memory leaks in the application.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually I have to blame myself for the memory leak because I am also the developer ;) I have tried to use only `MemoryMax` setting, but the process still stays in "D" status. Does it matters that celery service spawns child process to execute the tasks?

Comment: @sblandin Are you quite sure it's because of the memory limit, then? About 99.99% of the time D status is because the process is waiting on I/O. See [here](https://serverfault.com/a/942525/126632) for some ideas.

Comment: @Micheal Hampton I am sure that has something to do with memory limit. I'll update my question to give some additional information

Comment: @MichaelHampton "it may be suspended in the manner you describe" can you explain how can I do that? Or point to where it is in the docs? Thanks!